# Disable asp controls according to status of request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new in programing.

Suppose I have request numbers, and each of them is under one of the following 3 cases:

1. new
2. in progress
3. completed

And I have a web form in which its asp controls can be edited if the request number belong to case 1 or 2, and should be disabled if it is under case 3..

Please help in writing simple code for this.. C#.

Thanks

Comment: Can you further explain / show code where you are getting the status? Are you pulling from database? In any case, once you have the status, it's a simple `if else` statement or `switch case` statement to call `control.Enabled = false;` if the status is `3`.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TxTBox1"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


 Session["RequsetNo"] ="1";  ///Request no. is taken from other pages

        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["RequsetNo"]) == 3)
        {
            TxTBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

or

```
 int RequsetNo = 1;    //locally assigned
        if (RequsetNo == 3)
        {
            TxTBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
```